# Best way to expose a js lib if it's not being required or imported

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a small lib to be used with a animation canvas lib. Most of these folks don't use requireJS, webpack or any of this.

What's the best way to expose to the global if the file is directly referenced in the html?

```js
class MyLibClass {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
}

if (???) {
    // The user is importing or requiring it
    export default MyLibClass;
} else {
    // Expose to the global scope
     window.MyLibClass = MyLibClass;
}
```

Comment: Provide a UMD wrapper for your library. https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: first: you cannot export/import inside if statements. second: are you asking for es6 solution? or old module solutions?

Comment: @AhmadBamieh I thought browsers didn't support ES6 modules yet

Comment: true, but we have babel to handle that, check this out http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-umd/

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach, basically the idea is to detect if the environment provides any way to export the library, and if all fails, you fall back to a single global variable.

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(factory);
    } else if (typeof module != "undefined" && typeof module.exports != "undefined") {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else if (typeof Package !== "undefined") {
        MyLib= factory();  // export for Meteor.js
    } else {
        /* jshint sub:true */
        window["MyLib"] = factory();
    }
}(function () {
    ...
    return myLib;
}));
```

Note that it is written in ES5, not ES6, but it should be easy to recycle, the supported export methods are AMD, RequireJS (and ES6+), Meteor.js and the browser.

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 solution

### Importing Without Bindings

Some modules may not export anything, and instead, only make modifications to objects in the global scope. Even though top-level variables, functions, and classes inside modules don’t automatically end up in the global scope, that doesn’t mean modules cannot access the global scope. The shared definitions of built-in objects such as Array and Object are accessible inside a module and changes to those objects will be reflected in other modules.

For instance, if you want to add a pushAll() method to all arrays, you might define a module like this:

```
// module code without exports or imports
Array.prototype.pushAll = function(items) {

    // items must be an array
    if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
        throw new TypeError("Argument must be an array.");
    }

    // use built-in push() and spread operator
    return this.push(...items);
};
```

This is a valid module even though there are no exports or imports. This code can be used both as a module and a script. Since it doesn’t export anything, you can use a simplified import to execute the module code without importing any bindings:

```
import "./example.js";

let colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
let items = [];

items.pushAll(colors);
```

**Source:** An awesome book by Nicholas C. Zakas, Understanding ECMAScript 6.